# AWS cloud trail events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

Why do we need to choose us-east-1 as our region when to viewing CreateUser events in cloudtrail?
Is there a guide that describes this.
Note: my trails are in eu-west1 and are multi region.

Checking the events in my region

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events-cli.html

[sorry just saw this from the AWS documentation ]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).